# Should I be worried if none of my questions get answers?

Tags: discussion

If you look at my profile, you will see that I have asked four questions, none of which have answers.

To be clear, I am not complaining. Most of these questions were answered by comments. I think the phenomenon has something to do with not asking questions with 30 second answers that people looking for reputation answer (limit questions, HW, etc), but the questions tend to have answers elsewhere.

I was wondering if there is an automatic mechanism that might penalize me for having so many unanswered questions.

Comment: You can also add bounties to questions if they didn't receive an answer at all. Once I asked a question, which didn't receive an answer within $2$ days, and I placed a bounty. I obtained some very beautiful answers in the next few days.

Comment: Yes, I did use that functionality on the physics site. It worked. However, in these 4 cases, I either 1) got an answer or 2) realized that the answer is beyond my understanding as of now.

Comment: In the second case please feel free to ask the person about further clarifications.

Comment: None of your questions are copy-pasted homework questions, and so they get little attention. Join the club ;)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

None of your questions has a negative score, and three are at $+2$. So far none of them has even been downvoted once.

There is an automatic mechanism to penalise badly received questions - that is, downvoted or closed questions [duplicates are a different matter] - if you have too many badly received questions, your ability to ask further questions is reduced (rate-limiting) and in severe cases nullified (question-ban), but unanswered questions don't count against you.

So you need not worry.

If the question was answered in a comment, you could ask the comment-answerer to convert the comment to an answer, or write an answer yourself (crediting the commenter) to remove the question from the "Unanswered" list.

Comment: +1. And just adding..

"or write an answer yourself (crediting the commenter) to remove the question from the "Unanswered" list". 

When I do this, if the whole answer ended up being given in the comments, I make the answer CW.. I think it's even more polite to do it like this. Not my credit, right? My opinion on this, only (: